# server multithread answers only one client at once

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to create a multithread server which is talking to more than one client at the same time.
this is the issue :

- The server can answer only one client at once. I cannot send anything from the second client if the first one didn't get the server's response yet.

this is the code of my server :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;



public class Serveur extends Thread{


    private MyFrame mf;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private FileAttente file;
    private ServerSocket serveur ;



    public Serveur(int port,MyFrame f,FileAttente file) throws IOException{

         serveur = new ServerSocket(port);
         this.mf = f;
         this.file=file;
    }



    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mf.console.append("\nServeur en écoute ... ");
        while(true){
            try { 

                SoClient threadClient = new SoClient(this.serveur.accept());
                threadClient.start();
                mf.console.append("\nUn nouveau client s'est connecté");

            } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}



        }
        }






}
```

I also have this line : `mf.console.append("\nUn nouveau client s'est connecté");` executed after receiving each message from a client. Normally, it should be executed only when a new client comes.

this is the code of the socket where i put all the operations between client and server :

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;


public class SoClient extends Thread {

        static MyFrame mf;
        FileAttente file;
        public static Socket client;
        public SoClient(Socket client){
            this.client=client;
        }



        public void run(){

            MyFrame.console.append("\nConnexion établi : "+client.getInetAddress());
            //Envoie et reception
            try {
                InputStream in = this.client.getInputStream();
                OutputStream out = client.getOutputStream();

                sleep(2);

                DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(in);
                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                String request = is.readLine();
                MyFrame.console.append("\nMessage d'un Client :"+request);  
                DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(in);
                sleep(2);
                String chaine_Client=din.readUTF();
                MyFrame.console.append("Client :"+chaine_Client);
                client.close();
            }   catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {}
        }




    }
```

So, what I want to do, is sending a broadcast message from the server to all the clients which are connected or, send an echo message.
For the client, I created a class, and I instantiate it as much time as I want.
The Client class and the servers classes are in two diffirents projects in Eclipse.

Comment: Have you tried use Netty project framework?

Comment: No, I have never used it

Comment: Have you looked into RMI for your server? It handles having multiple clients sending to the server concurrently. For the other way (broadcast), your clients would also need to export a Remote Object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined the class-variable client in SoClient as static:

```
public static Socket client;
```

and set it in the constructor.

If you have multiple instances of SoClient, they all work on the same client-Socket.
That could cause more weird errors.

Remove the static keyword and it, hopefully, works.